# How can I delete from a table matching string?

Tags: mysql, database

I want to DELETE FROM my_table WHERE email does not contain "gmail" in the text.

How can I match it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [INSTR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)

```
DELETE FROM my_table
WHERE instr(`email`, 'gmail') = 0
```

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd192/1)

Comment: That deleted all the rows?

Comment: No, it deletes the rows that do not contain `gmail` in the `email`.

Comment: Oh my bad, I did 'email' instead of `email`, and it deleted everything :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'NOT LIKE' AS follows:

```
    DELETE FROM my_table WHERE email NOT LIKE '%gmail%'
```

Answer (score 0):

DELETE FROM my_table WHERE email NOT REGEXP 'gmail'